# most light/simple way to deploy static html/css/js (minimize, localisation, upload on server in one command)

Tags: deployment, gulp, gruntjs, integration, translation

From one command line, what is the simplest way to :

1. minimize static html, css, js, png, jpeg
2. replace translation to form multiple static pages
3. upload the minimized files on a server

For the **translation** part :

```
index.html with :
 supersite-en_UK.po supersite-de_DE.po supersite-fr_FR.po supersite-es_ES.po
```

.. will result as :

```
index.html , fr/index.html , de/index.html , es/index.html
```

, with all these sites being static files, minimized.

The tool should be one software or one script usable from (at least) Linux - so the user has just to press a button or run a command to make all the magic work.

As input **configuration**, it should have what folder it should get the files (*html,js,css,images*), and where it should get the *po* files, and the ftp connection details. That's (about) it.

All in all, it is a static website with 1 to 3 pages per language - with no server dynamics (no node, no php, no java, no ruby). So no need to install a jenkins server or alike.

So super-simple!! Super simplest simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile). Define `rules` e.g. minify, translate, publish, etc. to reflect what your project needs and finally define a default that calls these `rules` following your deployment pipeline. Running `make` from your project directory is your one command.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. Makefile, to me, is more about project compilation (like C projects to compile). Your answer suggests that it can also help handling things like for really simple web-based projects (translation, minimization, ftp/scp on a server). Can it *actually* help for all that ?? (surprise question!)

Comment: You can do in a Makefile anything you can from your CLI.